# How can I find out how many Science Stockpiles have I activated?

Tags: endless-legend

I'm currently playing as Cultists, which means I get a lot of Industry and Science Stockpiles. As I understand it, I can use at most stockpile per turn (and per city in the case of Industry Stockpiles).

With Industry Stockpiles, it's easy to check how many activated stockpiles (or "boosters") are remaining on the city screen:

[image: City screen with 8 remaining activated Industry Stockpiles]

But Science Stockpiles apply to the whole empire, not just a single city, so they're not shown on the city screen:

[image: City screen, the activated Science Stockpiles are not shown]

But they're also not shown in the Empire Bonuses section of the Empire Screen:

[image] [image]

So, is there some way to see them?

Comment: Either I have a bugged game, or you're misunderstanding. I have used over 10 stockpiles on the same city in the same turn. I didn't do anything special, just kept clicking the stockpiles until I had given the city the amount of production I wanted.

Comment: @DirtyBeach I don't have issues with using stockpiles. What I don't know is how to find out how many Science Stockpiles are currently active.

Comment: I understand that, I was referring to your mention of only being able to use one per turn. "As I understand it, I can use at most stockpile per turn (and per city in the case of Industry Stockpiles)." That is incorrect. You can use as many as you want.

Comment: @DirtyBeach Sure, you can activate more of them at once, but they won't be actually used all on the same turn.

Comment: I don't have the game with me to check right now, but I seem to recall being able to see this by mousing over the current science amount to see all the bonuses and maluses. Maybe that was Endless Space.

Answer (score 5):

As you've found, science stockpiles are not listed for individual cities, nor are they listed as an empire booster. The only location that seems to indicate that you have used a science stockpile is the Research Statistics on the Research Screen.

Using more than one science booster in a single turn will have apply the effect of **one** science booster each turn until they have all had an effect. This is shown below replaying 2 turns, the second time applying 2 science boosters on the first turn.

[image]

If you think you have more science boosters than will be needed for the rest of the game you can dispose of them in other ways:

1: Trade to another faction - this has restrictions as shown below

2: Sell your stockpiles on the market - at a rapidly diminishing price

[image]
[image]

Comment: It has been a while, but I believe using multiple science stockpiles at once means they will be applied over multiple turns. Which is what the question was about.

Comment: @svick Oops, I misunderstood. I just tested that and you are correct, I am going to edit my answer